# SQL arithmetic operation on one table

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, jpa

Hello I have table for transactions. BigDecimal amount and Boolean outcome.
If outcome is true I have bought something, if false I sold something.
I want to get in single query the amount when I do something like this

```
SELECT (amount(when outcome is false) - amount(when outcome is true)) AS income 
FROM transaction WHERE (the condition I was unable to write);
```

Is there any way to do this in single query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Can you give the full structure of the `transaction` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN outcome THEN - amount ELSE amount END) as income 
FROM transaction;
```